# Transfer data from Windows Service to Console Application repeatedly

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

Here is my scenario, I have a windows service that runs a task every 20 minutes, the task is: requesting updates from an API hosted by a remote website.

The response is a list of JSON objects, When the Service receives the list, it carries out a set of operations then appends more JSON objects, finally the service must push the list to a running console application.

**My very specific question is**: how to transfer this data from the windows service to the console App both **directly** and **professionally**

By *directly* I mean  **without intermediate solution** like writing in a temp file or saving in SQL table ... etc.

By *professionally* I mean the best optimal solution especially without p/Invoke from the service to the console App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would definitely need a medium to communicate between these two processes. The communication can be done in a lot of ways on the same system.

With your explanation in Question it looks like one way communication. May be you can go for Inter-process communication via sockets(raw level) or Use a messaging framework for communication(WCF/SignalR) or you can even use a Message Queue system(MSMQ/RabbitMQ) etc.

You can get a specific answer if you can narrow down your question.

Comment: Your comment is extremely helpful, I like the idea of RabbitMQ ... only small question ... does it manage string blobs ? or only binary?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41045900/c-sharp-transfer-a-variant-from-form1-cs-to-program-cs/41046077#41046077) that has some applicable code. Basically, the OP there wanted to send strings from a Windows Forms application to a console application and have the console application print the strings.

My recommendation is to use a Message Queue.

A few quick notes: first, you may have to [enable the feature in Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730960(v=ws.11).aspx) if you've never done so. Also, I guess under certain configurations of Windows you can't create the Message Queue directly from C#; if that's the case for you, you can create it manually (or there's probably a way to do it as part of an install script or something).

Here's the Windows Forms code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Or whatever name you end up calling it if you created the queue manually
    const string myQueue = ".\\myQueue";

    // It's possible that this won't work on certain computers
    // If not, you'll have to create the queue manually
    // You'll also need to turn the Message Queueing feature on in Windows
    // See the following for instructions (for Windows 7 and 8): https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc730960(v=ws.11).aspx
    if (!MessageQueue.Exists(myQueue))
    {
        MessageQueue.Create(myQueue);
    }

    using (MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(myQueue))
    {
        queue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new[] { typeof(string) });
        queue.Send("Test");
    }
}
```

Console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Or whatever name you use
    const string myQueue = ".\\myQueue";

    // See my comment on the corresponding line in the Windows Forms application
    if (!MessageQueue.Exists(myQueue))
    {
        MessageQueue.Create(myQueue);
    }

    MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(myQueue);
    queue.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new[] { typeof(string) });

    while (true)
    {
        Message message = queue.Receive();
        string messageText = message.Body.ToString();

        // Close if we received a message to do so
        if (messageText.Trim().ToLower() == "exit")
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(messageText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, it seems that RabbitMQ is exactly what I need, I will keep your answer for future ref. again thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

A nice, clean, 'modern' way of doing this, would be to host a Web API directly in the console application, and accept JSON input.

This is relatively easy to set up, and very easy to test and use.

Other methods include .NET remoting (which is not very modern any more), some other kind of service, like WCF, or any of the multitude of windows IPC methods.

Comment: I can't change the architecture, the Console App also running scheduled tasks, Thank you for your reply

Comment: @doe_deo If you can't make any changes to the console application, then why are you asking the question? 0.o

Comment: I can't make changes to the architecture not to the console app