# Is it possible to "launch" a copy of a (large) file without waiting for the result?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, xcopy

I think it's pretty obvious in the title ; I want to copy a file without waiting for the result.

Functionaly I want this :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strCmdText = @"/C xcopy c:\users\florian\desktop\mytestfile.fil p:\";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
        Console.WriteLine("Finished !");
    }
```

Basically my main thread is released after few milliseconds.
I try to do like this :

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = Task.Run(() => Copy(@"c:\Users\florian\Desktop\mytestfile.fil", "p:"));
    }

    private static void Copy(string source, string destination)
    {
        using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(source, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (FileStream DestinationStream = File.Create(destination + source.Substring(source.LastIndexOf('\\'))))
            {
                SourceStream.CopyToAsync(DestinationStream);
            }
        }
    }
```

My mytestfile.fil is created in my destination folder but its size is 0kb.

Regards,

Comment: In your main you'll have to wait for the Task to complete (Task.Wait(...)). Otherwise the console exits and terminates the worker thread

Comment: So... what's wrong with the first approach (using `cmd.exe` and `Process.Start`)?  If that's what you want, what about it doesn't work for you?

Comment: @samir Yes but I don't want wait ;-)

Comment: You cannot shut down the process and still have a thread that you started within the same process keep running. The process owns the threads and they will be terminated when the process ends. That's why you must keep the process (application) alive somehow as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: Unless there's processing happening after the async call the main thread will exit, taking the child with it.  I don't see the need for this to happen if you're processing can't proceed till the file write is complete.  You won't be able to avoid waiting on the child worker...

Answer (score 5):

> Basically my main thread is released after few milliseconds. I try to do like this

You must keep the process alive somehow. The easiest way to do this - if you actually have to do the file copy on a thread of its own - is to execute your Copy method on a *foreground* thread:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(()=> Copy(@"c:\Users\florian\Desktop\mytestfile.fil", "p:"));
        thread.Start();
    }

    private static void Copy(string source, string destination)
    {
        using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(source, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (FileStream DestinationStream = File.Create(destination + source.Substring(source.LastIndexOf('\\'))))
            {
                SourceStream.CopyTo(DestinationStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...or you could execute it on the main thread since your application doesn't seem to anything else:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string source = @"c:\Users\florian\Desktop\mytestfile.fil";
        string destination = "p";
        using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(source, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (FileStream DestinationStream = File.Create(destination + source.Substring(source.LastIndexOf('\\'))))
            {
                SourceStream.CopyTo(DestinationStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A third option is to make your method async and wait for it to complete synchronously in the Main method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CopyAsync(@"c:\Users\florian\Desktop\mytestfile.fil", "p:").Wait();
    }

    private static async Task CopyAsync(string source, string destination)
    {
        using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(source, FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (FileStream DestinationStream = File.Create(destination + source.Substring(source.LastIndexOf('\\'))))
            {
                await SourceStream.CopyToAsync(DestinationStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you should not use the asyncronous CopyToAsync method unless you actiually await it. Don't mix synchronous and asynchronous code :)

Comment: I've tried your code it's the same... the file is created but not copied. (0kb)

Comment: Also Thread is legacy code don't use this ! I don't have any idea why is upvoted !

Comment: Oh, you must use the synchronous CopyTo method or await the CopyToAsync method. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

OK more than one error.

- Your program exits before the copy completes. you need something like:
- CopyToAsync was not awaited

  ```
  class Program
  {
      private static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
          Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) =>
          {
              e.Cancel = true;
              source.Cancel();
          };

      try
      {
          MainAsync(args, source.Token).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
          return;
      }
      catch (OperationCanceledException)
      {
          return;
      }
  }

  static async Task MainAsync(string[] args, CancellationToken token)
  {
      var t = Task.Run(() => Copy(@"c:\test.txt", @"c:\dest\"));
      Console.WriteLine("doing more stuff while copying");
      await t;
      Console.WriteLine("Finished !");
  }

  private static void Copy(string source, string destination)
  {
      using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(source, FileMode.Open))
      {
          using (FileStream DestinationStream = File.Create(destination + source.Substring(source.LastIndexOf('\\'))))
          {
              SourceStream.CopyTo(DestinationStream);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: ``async Task`` not ``async void``

Comment: async void is okay for console application: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208921/cant-specify-the-async-modifier-on-the-main-method-of-a-console-app . Also he can just write Task.Wait() like  Stephen Cleary mention in the comments. I think this answer should be the correct one.

Comment: ok tested and working. also changed the async main so you dont need a library

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this might be an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Keep in mind that the OS/framework is basically giving your process its own "space" to run in, so the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var t = Task.Run(() => Copy(@"c:\Users\florian\Desktop\mytestfile.fil", "p:"));
}

private static void Copy(string source, string destination)
{
    using (FileStream SourceStream = File.Open(source, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (FileStream DestinationStream = File.Create(destination + source.Substring(source.LastIndexOf('\\'))))
        {
            SourceStream.CopyToAsync(DestinationStream);
        }
    }
}
```

is no different in terms of performance than just doing

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Copy(@"c:\Users\florian\Desktop\mytestfile.fil", "p:");
}
```

Since your console application fundamentally isn't doing anything other than copying the file, the extra thread just adds overhead.

Also, if you're using asynchronous operations inside the Copy method, you should declare your method `async Task` rather than `void` because otherwise you can't use the `await` keyword inside the `Copy` method or wait for the `Copy` method to complete elsewhere in code. So:

```
private static async Task Copy(string source, string destination)
```

As written, this has a blatant race condition and probably won't work correctly because `DestinationStream` and `SourceStream` may be disposed of before `SourceStream.CopyToAsync(DestinationStream)` has actually finished. You need to do

```
await SourceStream.CopyToAsync(DestinationStream);
```

inside your method to prevent this.

If you're launching the Copy operation with

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(...);
```

you're already effectively running this asynchronously from the perspective of the program that launched it because the program that launched it doesn't wait for the process to complete before it continues. Incidentally, I assume that that console application will do something other than just launch the process, correct? (If not, it seems a little redundant).

Comment: Yes of course. It's just to demonstrate what I want

Comment: Finally it's maybe not the good way to do this. May be I'll use a queue system (MSMQueue or other).

Comment: @Florian If you're interested in that I have a code sample [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41069723/transfer-data-from-windows-service-to-console-application-repeatedly/41071172#41071172) for what it's worth.

Answer (score 1):

Your Main method returns before the Task has completed, so your application ends.